# For loop code doubles spacing on x-axis every loop

Tags: javascript, jsx, photoshop-script

I'm trying to create a pattern script in Photoshop that duplicates an image horizontally and vertically over the whole canvas. But the issue is that across the x-axis it doubles its value every loop. If I remove the "j" loop, it works fine.

This pic will show you the issue I'm referring to https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkPrX.jpg

```
        var offset = parseInt(prompt("Type in the offset (spacing between pics) value here.\nDefault is 0px.", "0"));
        for (var i = 0; i < width / (layerWidth + offset); i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                app.activeDocument.layers[i, j].duplicate()
                app.activeDocument.layers[i, j].translate(i * (layerWidth + offset), j * (layerHeight + offset));
            }
        }
```

Comment: ```layers[i, j]``` is not a valid way to access the jth item in the ith row in a javascript array. You need ```layers[i][j]```.

Comment: The moment I changed it to that and run the code, this popped up: https://imgur.com/a/6XnnUPM

Comment: Well that means that layers is not an array of arrays. I'm not familiar with photoshop scripting framework, but by a quick look ```app.activeDocument.layers``` is an array of Layers and cannot be indexed further. If you want to access layers of that layer you need to do ```app.activeDocument.layers[i].layers[j]``` according to https://illustrator-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/jsobjref/Layer/ and https://illustrator-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/jsobjref/Layers/.

Comment: That didn't work either. I'm guessing photoshop scripting framework is a little different to illustrator. Is there another way I might be able to accomplish this if For Loop isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As volcanic mentioned, `layers[i, j]` isn't a valid way of accessing your layers. I'm not even sure why this works. You're supposed to select you original layer, make a copy and translate it. Something like this:

```
var width = activeDocument.width.as("px");
var height = activeDocument.height.as("px");
var layer = app.activeDocument.activeLayer;
var layerWidth = layer.bounds[2] - layer.bounds[0];
var layerHeight = layer.bounds[3] - layer.bounds[1];
var copy, i, j;

var offset = parseInt(prompt("Type in the offset (spacing between pics) value here.\nDefault is 0px.", "0"));   

for (i = 0; i < width / (layerWidth + offset); i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < height / (layerHeight + offset); j++)
    {
        // in the each loop we select the original layer, make a copy and offset it to calculated values
        app.activeDocument.activeLayer = layer;
        copy = layer.duplicate();
        copy.translate(i * (layerWidth + offset), j * (layerHeight + offset));
    }
}

layer.remove(); // remove the original layer
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This works beautifully :) I'm still getting used to the photoshop scripting framework

Comment: Good luck, it's a bit... special

Answer (score 0):

the issue is related  in how do you use `offset`: 
Translate refers to the bounding rect of the layer.
If you have a 50px width image translated by 50px, the resulting layer width will be 100px.
Try to use only the `offset`, each iteration.

Comment: Even if I remove the offset variable, the spacing issue still occurs. My loop codes aren't the culprit in this?